# Segmentation fault(core dumped) variable assignment

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

I have a program written in C++, compiled with G++, running in Ubuntu 13.04 32 bits, that is giving the following error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
printf("1\n");
int x = 0 , y = 0, count = 0;
printf("2\n");
char c;
printf("3\n");
int n_frames = (atoi(argv[1]) - 1);
printf("4\n");
int windowSize = WINDOW_SIZE; // WINDOW_SIZE is a define
printf("5\n");
// And the program go on....

long double frames[n_frames][377];

long double dis_frames[n_frames - (windowSize - 1)];
int tam_dis_frames = n_frames - (windowSize - 1);
long double white_top_hat[tam_dis_frames];
```

When the "n_frames" value (the one brought by argv[1]) is lower (tested until 300) the error does not happen and everything goes fine.

When the value is higher (like 1922) the error happens. When the error happens the last printf that is shown is the fourth one, "printf("4\n")".

When the value is 1853 or lower the "printf("5\n")" is shown but the next printf wont show up.

Anyone has any idea what could solve it? What could be the source of Segmentation fault(core dumped) in a so simple step of the program....

Comment: how do you start that program? that is, whats argv[1]

Comment: What input are you providing? Printg argc and argv for diagnostics. Also, pretend you never heard of atoi and printf and learn C++.

Comment: The first step to debugging something like this is to try to reproduce the error with a *minimal* program.  E.g. in this case, try getting rid of all statements before `int n_frames...`.  Does the error still occur?

Comment: last printf is not shown because it has been executed but it's in buffer ready to be printed. However the seg fault is not in this code, add more code please.

Comment: program is executed as follow: ./Program.exe 1922

Comment: argc value is "2", atoi(argv[1]) is the number 1922 that i sent, printet that with printf and is printing right, just edited with more lines of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `frames` array is created on the stack using a dynamic size passed in by the user on the command line.  You're already out of standard C++ territory here and using an extension/C99ism referred to as "Variable Length Arrays".

Furthermore, the `n_frames` value you passed in (1922) makes the frames array 1922*377*10 bytes long, i.e. roughly 7.5 MB.  On just about any standard desktop/laptop machine/OS, your stack size limit is roughly 1MB, so you're broken in two different ways.

The obvious, direct solution to your problem is to dynamically allocate `frames` like so:

```
long double** frames = new (long double*)[n_frames];
for (int i = 0; i < n_frames; ++i) {
  frames[i] = new long double[377];
}
```

...and of course don't forget the corresponding `delete []`'s at the end.

However, that said, you'll probably want to learn about `std::vector` as the de facto dynamically allocated array class in C++.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but got segmentation fault in other parts of the program. Guess i need to study more of C/C++ to know how these memory allocations works.

Comment: @dragons You should avoid raw allocations competely

Answer (score 1):

This is an stack overflow. You are using a number of variable length arrays (VLA) and for large values of n_frames you overflow the stack. Use dynamically allocated memory instead.

I suspect you did not even realise that you were using VLAs. They are a very easy feature to misuse and unless you really understand the full implications of their use you should avoid them.

Your code looks much more like C than C++. In my view it is time for you to learn how to do things the C++ way. You should really be avoiding raw memory allocation. And you should certainly not be calling printf and never ever call atoi.